# pdfLaTeX in Aquamacs

Tags: pdftex

I have installed Aquamacs, but it looks like it is connecting pdfTeX to compile pdf's
instead of the pdfLaTeX. 
how can I change the path or  the link to the compiler?

Comment: If my answer is wrong, it would help if you could post the first few lines of a .log file, if any is generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you open any tex file with Aquamacs, you can go to LaTeX -> Customize AUCTeX -> Extend this menu. Then, at LaTeX -> Customize AUCTeX, you have access to every options. In particular, you can check what is associated to the LaTeX command.

Answer (score 1):

This should not happen, and I guess that in fact you are running `pdflatex`.

What can cause confusion is that calling either `pdftex` or `pdflatex`  invokes the same binary, just telling it whether to use macros for Plain Tex or Latex.

The first line of the .log file will begin "This is pdfTeX" even when invoked as `pdflatex`.  You have to look further down the log file to see if you are in fact running Latex: see if there is a line beginning "LaTeX2e".